# How to set focus on dropdown list, using javascript, php

Tags: php, javascript, focus, drop-down-menu, set

I am unable to set focus to my php page dc-test.php (this is a **frames page**: topFrame and botFrame) dropdown list, which has **2 dropdown** lists and are dependent. 
These dropdown lists values are populated from a table.
Unable to **set focus for the first dropdown** and later after the reload for the second dependent dropdown list. Pl see my code below, need your help ! Sorry if i am repeating this question on this forum, because I was unable to find the right answer.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html>
    <head>
    <SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
    function reload(form)
    {
    var val=form.cat.options[form.cat.options.selectedIndex].value;
    self.location='dc-test.php?cat=' + val ;
    }

    function firstfield()
    {
    document.topFrame.cat.focus();
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body onLoad="firstfield();">

    <?php
    $dbservertype='mysql';
    $servername='localhost';
    $dbusername='aaa';
    $dbpassword='234!@';
    $dbname='test';

    connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
    function connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$dbuser,$dbpassword)
    {
    global $link;
    $link=mysql_connect ("$servername","$dbuser","$dbpassword");
    if(!$link){die("Could not connect to MySQL");}
    mysql_select_db("$dbname",$link) or die ("could not open db".mysql_error());
    }
    // End of DB connection

    @$cat=$_GET['cat'];
    if(strlen($cat) > 0 and !is_numeric($cat)){ 
    echo "Data Error";
    exit;
    }


    $quer2=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT Ac_desc, Ac_code FROM ACMAST order by Ac_desc");


    /////// Second drop down list we will check if category is selected else we will display all the subcategory/////
    if(isset($cat) and strlen($cat) > 0){
    $quer=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT Add1 FROM ACMAST where Ac_code=$cat order by   Add1");
    }

    echo "<form name='f1'>";
    echo "<table width='100%' height='39'  border='0' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0'>";
    echo "  <tr>";
    echo "    <td width='12%'>.</td>";
    echo "    <td width='7%'><span class='sty1'> Customer</span></td>";
    echo "    <td width='27%'><select name='cat' onchange=\"reload(this.form);        showUser(this.value);\">
    <option value=''>Select Name</option>";
    while($noticia2 = mysql_fetch_array($quer2)) {
    if($noticia2['Ac_code']==@$cat){echo "<option selected value='$noticia2[Ac_code]'>$noticia2[Ac_desc]</option>"."<BR>";}
    else{echo  "<option value='$noticia2[Ac_code]'>$noticia2[Ac_desc]</option>";}
    }
    echo "</select>";

    echo "</td>";
    echo "    <td width='6%'><span class='sty1'>Address</span></td>";
    echo "    <td width='48%'> </span><select name='subcat'>";
    while($noticia = mysql_fetch_array($quer)) {
    echo  "<option value='$noticia[Add1]'>$noticia[Add1]</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "  </tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
    </body>        
    </html>
```

Comment: Just curious why do you have two doctypes?

Comment: Really didn't get what you are asking for. Focus on both dropdowns? You can focus only one element. What the problem is and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: What I want is simple. The first time 2 dropdown lists are displayed, the focus has to set for first drowndown list and when an item is selected in first dropdown the page reload and a value is populated in the second dropdown list and focus needs to be set for this.

Comment: Is there anybody who can help me on this issue, please respond !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "topFrame" is completely out of scope here:

```
function firstfield()
{
document.topFrame.cat.focus();
}
```

Do this instead:

Give the form field an id:

```
echo "    <td width='27%'><select name='cat' id='cat' onchange=\"reload(this.form); showUser(this.value);\">
```

Change firstfield to this:

```
function firstfield()
{
document.getElementById('cat').focus();
}
```

And, on an unrelated note: make your life easier and start using jQuery. :)

Comment: Eric, even this does't work, i am using firefox 9.01, is this a browser problem, by the way how do we do the same using jQuery can you give an example.

Comment: I had set the focus to the form, not the form field. That's fixed in the above answer now which I've verified works. As for jQuery, I'd just take a look at http://jquery.com/.

Comment: Eric, This works fine thank you ! I also tried jquery which is a much better option with great control, thank you very much.            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('form input:text:enabled:first').focus();
        });
       </script>

With this only problem is it does't set the foucs to dropdown, is there something missing.